# Passing Static List To a view MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a static class that contains a list which is filled by each model. What I'm tring to achieve by this is to have every model in one big list, then have that list sorted by date. Then have each class displayed in one big table (via partial views) in that order. heres the static class:

```
    public static class Inq_MasterList {
    public static List<Inq_DetailsBase> DetailsList = new List<Inq_DetailsBase>();


    public static List<Inq_DetailsBase> CombineModels() {


        DetailsList.Sort((x, y) =>
            x == null ? (y == null ? 0 : -1) : (y == null ? 1 : x.EventDate.CompareTo(y.EventDate))
        );

        return DetailsList;
    }
}
```

i have a "master" view page that contains a model reference, but I am trying to pass this specific static list as sort of a detail section that does not match the model (i hope that makes sense). So I am testing on one of the "detail" views with a call to DisplayFor like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Inq_MasterList.DetailsList, "Inq_HotScaleDetail")
```

however, now i am getting an error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How can I explicitly pass this list to the view?
or am I going about this "master/details" wrong?

when I cast it, I get a null reference exception, even though I have items in the list:

```
@Html.DisplayFor((Inq_CompositeChain x) => Inq_MasterList.DetailsList, "Inq_HotScaleDetail")
```

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayFor` requires an *expression* as its input.  It parses the expression to find any relevant metadata for the member that the expression references.

You can try

```
@Html.DisplayFor( () => Inq_MasterList.DetailsList, "Inq_HotScaleDetail")
```

But I'm not sure you can use a field in this way.  Public fields are frowned on in general, so a public property or method would be better.  You can keep a *private* field and just return it in a method:

```
private static List<Inq_DetailsBase> _DetailsList = new List<Inq_DetailsBase>();

public IEnumerable<Inq_DetailsBase> DetailsList {get {return _DetailsList;}}
```